# Is It possible to configure the width of pages developed using napili temlate in communities?

Tags: community, customer-community

We are using `Napili template` to build our community pages,By default the pages width are set to box size and they are not spreading across the complete available window space. Is there setting available in communities to adjust the width of pages so that the pages are spread across the complete available window space

Answer (score 5):

The detail pages have the full width when using `Napili template`. You can refer to the [Community Templates Guide](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/16/en-us/sfdc/pdf/community_templates.pdf) - Chapter Display Record Details in Your Community.

An example of a detail page using this template

[image]

You can configure the layout of detail pages as per your preferences by going to `Settings -> Community Builder -> Page Management`

This has a record headline and record information and both are set to full width. There is obviously left and right padding which you can't override.