# How can report width be increased in a Customer Service (Napili) Community?

Tags: community, reporting, css, napili, lightning-community

In Salesforce, reports display at almost full width on a 1920 x 1080 screen, 1878px to be exact.

However, in our Customer Service Community, reports show at a width of 1109px (in the report summary component). There is a ton of wasted space on either side, and some reports have many rows, which means that in order to scroll horizontally, you first have to scroll all the way down. If users want to see columns at the top right side of the report, they have to scroll all the way down, then over, and then all the way back up. Because of this, our users are exporting reports to Excel just to view them, especially since column size is fixed.

Is there a way to take advantage of the full width of the screen for reports like in Salesforce itself?

This related [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103890/is-it-possible-to-configure-the-width-of-pages-developed-using-napili-temlate-in) talks about page width, but is either outdated or doesn't seem to offer a solution that applies to reports.

Comment: were you able to create a custom theme layout with the properties you need in regards to the width you require for your reports?

Answer (score 0):

The container where the component is dropped in the default page template is scoped with a max-width of x.

> .cCenterPanel

therefore, you can change the [community branding](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_designer_brand.htm&type=0) and override the max-width, however, this is likely to break if there is a change in the Napili template styling in a future release, OR you can create your own [Custom Theme layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm) for viewing records.

For Ex. if you change the max width from the default to 2000px you would change the layout from:
[image]
To:
[image]

However, notice that scoping your CSS with this class will affect all your pages, therefore, building your custom theme layout for displaying reports would be the best approach, and you will be able to set your own CCS rules.